# Eclipse plugins not loading automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have done a few Eclipse plugins, and when developing, I always place the new versions of the plugin into the `eclipse\plugins` folder on the installed Eclipse target, and when I launch Eclipse, they are loaded.

I'm now updating a plugin that was targeting Luna, now to work in Oxygen.3.  I've rebuilt the plugin using Oxygen.3 Eclipse for Eclipse Committers, and then place the resultant output `.jar` file into the target Eclipse `plugins` folder, along with the new dependencies my plugin needs (namely several WST modules).  But when I launch Eclipse, the plugin won't load automatically.

If I launch Eclipse with `-console` option, I can then try to manually load the plugin from the console:

```
osgi> install reference:file:plugins/com.mystuff_1.0.0.201805181701.jar
```

Then using the console `diag` command to check if the dependencies were satisfied, it gives:

```
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui; bundle-version="1.3.600"
```

I can then load that via console via `install` command:

```
install reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui_1.3.600.v201707042340.jar
```

diag again shows that the `wst.sse.ui` plugin has unresolved requirements - basically, repeat the cycle for each of the 8 WST related plugins that are in the dependency tree.  Finally, all dependencies are satisfied, the diag command gives:

```
osgi> diag 355
com.mystuff [355]
  No resolution report for the bundle.
```

At this point, my plugin is active and can be debugged.

What am I missing?  Why won't the plugins load automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the introduction of the [Provisioning platform (p2)](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_overview.htm) in Eclipse Ganymede (3.4) the **`plugins`** folder is no longer scanned for changes. Instead, the [**`dropins`** folder](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html) is scanned (see also [Eclipse 3.4 - New and Noteworthy - New dropins folder](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/whatsnew3.4/eclipse-news-all.html#equinox.p2.dropins)):

- Place the new versions of your plug-ins **into the `dropins` folder** instead of into the `plugins` folder.
- Alternatively, you can **install the plug-ins directly into your running Eclipse IDE when exporting** the plug-ins (see [Eclipse Help: Export and Install into the Running Host](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/ui_export_install_into_host.htm)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the response howlger, I did not know about the dropins folder.  Unfortunately, after trying it out, I am seeing the exact same behavior - i.e., I created new eclipse/plugins folder, placed my plugin and the dependencies from WST there, and restart Eclipse.  Still does not load them automatically, I can still load them manually through the console "install" command (but pointing to "reference:file:dropins/" now instead of "reference:file:plugins/").  What can still be blocking it?

Comment: With the plug-ins in the `dropins` folder you will get more details in the log file (_Error Log_ view).

Comment: Thanks again howlger.  Unfortunately it is not showing anything about my plugin...  However, I was able to take your advice and test loading it through the dropins folder, using a vanilla Eclipse Oxygen 3 install - that worked.  Which means the problem is specific to the customized Eclipse I am currently targeting.  So, that's progress at least - I couldn't get it to load automatically in the vanilla Eclipse before.  So now I just need to figure out what is missing or broken in the customized install to inhibit the automatic loading.